# Blackberry - "[projectname].debug file is missing" and "I/O Error: Cannot find program "jar"

Tags: java, blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I'm running eclipse with the Blackberry Java Plug-in, working on a 1.4.5 Blackberry project.
The project has been building and debugging in the emulator normally until I started getting:

A prompt saying "*[projectname].debug file is missing*".

A message in the Blackberry Packaging Console saying  "*I/O Error: Cannot find program "jar": CreateProcess error=2.*"

Anyone have any ideas what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that there can be a few different causes. In some instances, hitting the 100 class limit in the project can cause this.

In my case, the Environment Variable for Path in Windows > System Properties had disappeared.
Something to note is that when you put it back in (in my case "c:\program files\java\jdk1.6.0_18\bin") it needs to be the first entry in the path variable.

Answer (score 0):

right-click My Computer -> Properties -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables button

set the correct system variables, for example:

**JAVA_HOME**
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_30

**JRE_HOME**
C:\Program Files\Java\jre6