# Eclipse Debug Files Missing

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, blackberry

I am fairly new with the blackberry eclipse plugin and I am trying to figure out a way to debug an error I receive. Someone told me to right click on the project and Run As - > Blackbery Simulator. The issue is when I do that I get the error "The "[projectname].debug" file is missing. Please choose the missing file. With the options "Search...", "Browse...", "Cancel", and "Don't ask this again".

This is the first time I'm running the debugger and I'm very new to BB development altogether so I'm very confused on what to do.

I have consulted these sources:

http://www.blackberryforums.com/developer-forum/172233-missing-my-debug-file.html

and

[Blackberry - "[projectname].debug file is missing" and "I/O Error: Cannot find program "jar"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070970/blackberry-projectname-debug-file-is-missing-and-i-o-error-cannot-find-p)

along with others but some of the instructions seem dated with my version of eclipse (BB plugin 1.5, newest eclipse presumably). Any help on the matter would be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, a user from a blackberry forum stated that I should just click to not display again and this would work. So far it seems like this is the case.